# How to retrieve the data entered through a form (NOT through model form based on a model) in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm familiar with creating forms based on Model forms, in that case I can use `form.save()` to save the data in database. The question is, how do I save/retrieve the data of this form that I didn't create through a model form?

I've tried the following code but I'm not sure how to retrieve and save the data from `NameForm`.

```
#forms.py file:

from django import forms
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label = 'your name', max_length = 100)

# views.py file

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import NameForm

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'meal_plans/home.html')

def name(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = NameForm()
    else:
        form = NameForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            your_name = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
            return redirect('meal_plans:home')

    return render(request, 'meal_plans/name.html', {'form': form})

# name.html template

<form action="{% url 'meal_plans:home' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with `your_name`?

Comment: save all the names entered by the form and then show all of them through a template @DanielHolmes

Comment: Do you want to save them to a model?

Comment: this is what i want to ask? Do I have to create a model to save data or is there any way to save it without creating the model?

Comment: And if it is needed to create the model to save the data then what is the purpose of creating a form this way @DanielHolmes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to save the data in the users session. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/) explain quite nicely how to implement this. In your case, it would be something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    request.session['your_name'] = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
    ...
```

To access that session variable in another view, you would use:

```
your_name = request.session.get('your_name')
```